# Debug Phonegap for window phone

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7

How do I debug my jquery mobile app on a windows phone?

My current problem is that a link like this does not work:

```
<a href="#next_page" data-role="button" class="btn_main_next_collection"></a>
```

If I click on it, I see for a short moment a little black box (loding symbol?) but the app stays on the same page (div).

If I load the same page in the phones Internet Explorer it works.

How do I debug this?

**Update**

I updated to the [latest jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/16/latest/) version and now I get "Error Loading Page" like he is trying to load it as ajax but it is a multipage with the old rel="external" the error did not show up but it still did not work. (Same with jquery mobile 1.0.1)

**Update 2**

Creating a second page index2.html and setting a link like this works:

```
<a href="index2.html#next_collection" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" ...
```

But only if I use a different page. `index.html#next_collection` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by updating from phonegap 1.3.0 to 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Ripple mobile emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc). It has a setting for PhoneGap emulation.

Comment: It says it will be discontinued and I should install the new version: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple